# No menu to navigate to Badges for Tags from Badges page

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-badges

I found no way to navigate to [Help Center > Badges > Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags) from [Help Center > Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) except Google.

Please add the hyperlink back!

Comment: Click on the bronze, silver, or gold tag badge in the list. Then you can go to "all" if you *really* want a list of all of them mixed together. I've never seen a use in that page. I much prefer the separated ones.

Comment: @animuson: Interesting. And **not obvious**. Is it? :)

Comment: Well, you can ask to have the "Tag Badges" caption link to the tag badges page showing all of them. (the link you used in your example)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Basing on these two my questions and what I've learned, I'd expect Tag Badges link on Unearned tab to lead to Unearned Tag Badges. But links are equal on both tabs!